# Notice: Undefined variable: proid in D:\xampp\htdocs\staging\gvresearch1\con_golive.php on line 4

Tags: undefined

```
<?php
checkLogin();

$data = getProjectDetails($proid);
$data1 = getProjectDetails2($proid);
$member = getMemberLevel(2);

if($data==1 || $data1==1 || $member==1){
    include_once("./con_error1.php");
}else if(checkAuth(1)===true){
?>
```

I'm learning PHP this semester and I'm both enjoying it and immediately lost a bit on my first real assignment.

There are a few other similar questions but, because I'm new, I'm not able to extrapolate their answers to help with this.

Comment: What's your exact question? The headline is the error message you get, I assume, but no question.

Comment: It means you are not declaring `$proid` before you are trying to use it